# Subview reset to original frame after present view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Currently I have a problem when presenting a view controller.

I have a view with subviews inside. When data loaded, I change the frame of some `UILabel` to correct its position. I also have many photos and need to show slideshow of them.

The slideshow is called by this command:

```
 [self presentViewController:_photoNC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

After dismiss from this PhotoViewController by calling this command:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

The problem is all `UILabel` reset to their original frame. I can't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: This is probably a consequence of auto layout. If that is turned on, then you need to reposition your label using constraints, not setting frames.

Comment: Very very thanks. It solved problem.

Comment: @TrungBui Could you tell me more specific solution?

Comment: You need to find all view in your xib and turn off Use Autolayout, it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
myLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
```